# Akka testing - sender is deadLetters

Tags: scala, akka, scalatest

I've got the following test spec:

```
class SiteCheckerSpec extends TestKit(ActorSystem("testSystem"))
                     with ImplicitSender
                     with BeforeAndAfterAll
                     with Matchers
                     with WordSpecLike {

val sites = List(
   "www.google.com",
   "www.apple.com",
   "www.gazeta.pl"
)

"Tested SiteChecker actor" must {
  "not receive message" in {
      val testedActor = system.actorOf(Props(new SiteChecker(sites.size) with TestActorContextCreationSupport {
          override def actorRefFactory = system
      }))

      testedActor ! SiteChecker.CheckSitesTitles(sites)
      expectNoMsg()
  }
}

override protected def afterAll(): Unit = TestKit.shutdownActorSystem(system)
}
```

And following actor:

```
class SiteChecker(workersCount: Int) extends Actor
                                    with ActorLogging
                                    with ActorContextCreationSupport {

val resultMap = mutable.HashMap.empty[String, String]
var originalSender: Option[ActorRef] = None

val workers = (
  for (i <- 1 to workersCount) yield createChildren(SiteCheckerWorker.props())
).toList

def actorRefFactory: ActorRefFactory = context

override def receive: Actor.Receive = {

case SiteChecker.CheckSitesTitles(sites) =>
  log.info(s"Sites to check $sites")
  println(sender)
  originalSender = Some(sender)
  workers.zip(sites).foreach(
    t => t._1 ! SiteCheckerWorker.CheckSiteTitle(t._2)
  )

case SiteCheckerWorker.SiteTitle(site, title) =>
  log.info(s"Obtained title $title for site $site")
  resultMap += (site -> title)
  if (resultMap.size == workers.size) {
    originalSender.get ! SiteChecker.SitesTitles(resultMap.toMap)
    context.children.foreach(context.stop)
  }
}
}
```

Test case is always passing because `orginalSender` in actor class is `deadLetters`, not reference to test sender.

Here is the log output after test is run:

```
 Actor[akka://testSystem/deadLetters]
 [INFO] [02/13/2014 18:53:59.150] [testSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2]    [akka://testSystem/user/$a] Sites to check List(www.google.com, www.apple.com, www.gazeta.pl)
 [INFO] [02/13/2014 18:53:59.154] [testSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://testSystem/user/$a] Obtained title www.gazeta.pl for site www.gazeta.pl
 [INFO] [02/13/2014 18:53:59.157] [testSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://testSystem/user/$a] Obtained title www.google.com for site www.google.com
 [INFO] [02/13/2014 18:53:59.158] [testSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://testSystem/user/$a] Obtained title www.apple.com for site www.apple.com
 [INFO] [02/13/2014 18:53:59.163] [testSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://testSystem/deadLetters] Message [actor.site.SiteChecker$SitesTitles] from  Actor[akka://testSystem/user/$a#735871082] to Actor[akka://testSystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only possibility that I can see is that you have another `implicit ActorRef` in scope in your test procedure, leading to an ambiguous implicit argument which then means that none of them is picked up.

Comment: How can I start debugging it? Can you give me some tips, where these multiple implicit ActorRef's might be defined?

Comment: Hmm, difficult to say without seeing the code. What you could also try is to pass `testActor` explicitly as the sender (replacing `!` by `tell`).

Comment: As you said, there were multiple implicit ActorRef constants. After changing some code, everything started working as expected.

Answer (score 16):

In my case this happened because my test class extended `TestKit`, but **did not** mix in `ImplicitSender`.